# Remove all items from NSTreeController

Tags: objective-c, macos, xamarin, nstreecontroller, xamarin.mac

I would like to clear all items out of an NSTreeController that I added using Controller.AddObject. Is this possible? I presume it is possible to retrieve all the index paths, sort by depth in reverse and remove the items one by one, but I'm hoping for a way just to clear the data.

Answer (score 0):

Simply replace the whole tree model by calling `setContent:` on your `NSTreeController`.

This removes everything but makes adding new elements impossible:

```
[treeController setContent:nil];
```

Prefer to replace it with an empty collection instead:

```
[treeController setContent:@[]];
```

Depending on your model, you might need to do additional set-up for the collection.